# EF 6 IsRequired() allowing empty strings

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In past projects with versions of EF5 and EF4, the IsRequired() fluent API method would thrown a DbEntityValidationException if the property was null or an empty string.  In my current project utilizng EF6, The DBEntityValidationException is not thrown when the string property is empty.

**Entity:**

```
public class Application : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
internal class ApplicationMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMapping()
    {
        // table name
        this.ToTable("Applications");

        // properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

After pouring over the MSDN EF documentation and stack overflow, I am at a loss for why this is happening.  Did a convention get added/modified to EF6?

Comment: Have you registered your `EntityTypeConfiguration` inside the inside the `OnModelCreated` method? So with `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationMapping ());`

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the entity type configuration is instantiated when the model is created.  The IsRequired() is throwing the DBEntityValidationException when the Name property is null, but not when Name = string.Empty

Answer (score 35):

These days you can still use `[Required]` attribute and have configurable `AllowEmptyStrings`

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

False is default

Comment: I don't know why they would make it fail validation on empty strings.  Marking a column non-nullable isn't supposed to disallow empty strings.

Comment: My field is NOT NULL. But i should be able to insert empty string into it. When i had EF Database-first (edmx) it allowed empty string. Now I changed to EF Code-first, it automatically put the [Required] attribute on the prop and is disallowing empty string. Was struggling, until i saw your explanation, but it can be confusing (at the DB level there is no similar concept.. it doesn't care if your string is empty, has one char,  or 1000 chars !)

Comment: Actually. if you really need to insert an empty string. it is not enough to AllowEmptyStrings = true, you must also set ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false.

Answer (score 25):

You may be confusing the [StringColumnConfiguration.IsRequired Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringcolumnconfiguration.isrequired%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)  and [RequiredAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`.IsRequired()` marks that column in the database is `NOT NULL`.  The `[Required]` annotation however,  will raised a validation exception if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

Comment: this looks a good suggestion,  The fluent api is just not null for is requiried.  perhaps there was some other check you had before that was screening empty strings.

Comment: I've just verified that the [Required] attribute on a property will trigger a validation exception when the containing entity is tried to be stored with that property set to null or "". This is with EF6.

Comment: but the conflict here is that you set "not null" in DB and autogenerate poco classes in VS2015, Property is marked as [Required], then you think that you can insert String.Empty but it crashes. Is it a bug in EF poco generation?

Answer (score 3):

EF Core 2.1 here - looks like marking a property as required using [Required] and saving it to the DB with empty string value, let's it go through... very strange.

Documentation states the following:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a value that indicates whether an empty string is allowed.
//
// Returns:
//     true if an empty string is allowed; otherwise, false. The default value is false.
public bool AllowEmptyStrings { get; set; }
```

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute (from `DataAnnotations`) has different semantics based on the use context, unfortunately. For example, in JSON.NET schema validation it means that the JSON property must be present, but it can have a `null` or empty-string value. In ASP.NET MVC it does respect `AllowEmptyStrings` and means the property must have a value (but not if it's a Complex Property, annoyingly) and EF Core is doing its own thing too. Argh.