# EF6: migration generates nullable string despite IsRequired

Tags: entity-framework, non-nullable

I'm trying to generate a migration for a new Entity class that has a *string* field, called *"Name"*. That string field should not be nullable.

I'm aware that "nullable" and "non-empty" are two different issues (see [EF 6 IsRequired() allowing empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619632/ef-6-isrequired-allowing-empty-strings) ). But for now I just want to stick to non-null.

I'm failing to achieve that. The generated migration always ends up having *"nullable:true"*, as shown :

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Tags",
            columns: table => new
            {
                // ...
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                // ...
            },
            // ...
    }
```

I'm aware that I could achieve this with a annotation ( [EF6 Add-Migration for not nullable string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245628/ef6-add-migration-for-not-nullable-string) ) but our architect forbade those. I need to stick to the *Configure* function in *IEntityTypeConfiguration*.

I'm using *IsRequired()*.

```
public class TagEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tag> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Tag");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

    }
}
```

Why do I get nullable:true despite .IsRequired ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply forgetting to *use* the EntityTypeConfiguration :

```
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TagEntityTypeConfiguration());
```

Without this line the constraints are ignored.